# Input number in html textbox and check with php if user with this id exists in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to input number in textbox in html and check if user with that ID exists in database Delovni_Cas if it exist echo Success otherwise Failed. I managed to get it to work without `.$value.` and just manually entering number like 1,2,3,...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <form method="get">
      <INPUT TYPE = "Text" value="1" NAME = "IDU">
      <INPUT TYPE = "Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "perkowich";
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
      $value = $_POST['IDU'];

      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Delovni_Cas WHERE Zaposleni_ID_Osebe='".$value."'");
      if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {    
        echo "Sucess";
      } else {
        echo "Failed";
      } 
      $conn->close();
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Get method in form and using $_POST in php, Please use $_GET instead of $_POST to get form value.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, but even $_GET['IDU'] doesn't seem to do the trick. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: In your connection string you did not provide database name.